# Is there any way to get out of having 261+ MB of "dummy data" with each NW.js-powered application?

Tags: javascript, optimization, distribution, node-webkit

I use NW.js. It's basically like Electron, except a bit less sucky in some ways. But the basic point is that you distribute an entire gigantic Chromium build with every game/application you create with it.

That currently means **261 MB** on Windows, and even bigger on Linux/macOS.

If I 7-Zip that to a ZIP archive with "normal" compression, it becomes ~**97 MB**.

If I 7-Zip that to a ZIP archive with "ultra" compression, it becomes ~**96 MB**. Hardly any difference from "normal".

So at best about 100 megs plus actual application data to distribute over the Internet, and 261+ MB plus actual application data wasting storage on the customer's system, once installed.

As somebody who grew up with 1.44 MB 3½" floppy disks, often storing multiple games and programs on just one of those, this just feels horribly wrong to me. Heck, my first hard disk had a **total storage** of 270 MB!

Yeah, yeah, time marches on and technology improves etc., but still, I simply cannot get over the sheer amount of waste. I have a feeling that 99% of that data isn't actually being used or is necessary, but I wouldn't have any idea how one would remove it sensibly and reliably.

It just feels wrong to me to have that much overhead, no matter how common it may be.

Comment: This: "_except a bit less sucky in some ways_" - apparently not?

Comment: Seems this issue has been around a long time for nw.js https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/issues/3955

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately you are shipping a copy of Node.js and a browser. You can do a custom build of NW.js, this requires building Chromium from source (very complex and difficult). You can then chose to exclude portions of Chromium that your app will not use. Personally, I don't think the amount of effort to do this is worth it unless you've got a legitimate business case for it.

- https://nwjs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/For%20Developers/Building%20NW.js/

Alternatively, here is a detailed article on approaches for reducing the distribution size of your application, that **don't** require doing a custom build of NW.js.

- https://dev.to/thejaredwilcurt/reducing-app-distribution-size-in-nwjs-3d5f

Lastly, there are other options than NW.js and Electron, some focusing on producing very small dists. However, none will match the ease of development or robust features though.

- https://xpda.net

Comment: How exactly is Neutralinojs able to make such smaller applications compared to NW.js/Electron if it also uses Chromium?

Comment: Neutralino is a small executable that runs a static local http server to serve your application in the user's browser. It does not ship a browser, or a full copy of Node. It has a very light API and lacks most of the powerful features that NW.js offers. Look very carefully at what its API offers to make sure you won't need any more than that. It's very limited. But is maintained, so you may be able to make feature requests.